# How to set a content type tile base on taxonomy field that user select?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have ask in the past [How to convert Content Type Title into Term reference?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/148957/how-to-convert-content-type-title-into-term-reference/148968#comment181324_148968). Which someone suggest to used the [Title Field UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/title_field_ui) in order to remove it the title and have a Term Reference field as my title field.

However, now I run into few problems where the title field is been expected like `admin/page`. So I was wondering if possible to set up the title field the same as the a term but automatically. I do not want the user re-type the field Title field, but at the same time I want to limit the user from choosing something that is not from the terms.

So how can I copy the taxonomy term that the user select and set up as title programmatically ?

**Update 1**

My content type machine name is `job_per_template` and taxonomy name is `field_job_title_template`. I have take the code from the answer below and I got this error.

> Integrity check for the imported configuration failed. Error message:
>   The data type of the configured argument does not match the
>   parameter's `<em class="placeholder">value</em>` requirement..

[image]

Comment: I assume this is for Drupal 7? If so, you should be able to essentially either use the term reference as your Title field OR use a taxonomy token if you absolutely need the title field for some reason.

Comment: Yes, this is a D7 website. I disable the Title and I'm using the Term Reference as my title field. However, my title is been expected on other places. That's why I want to set my title base on what the user select ( in the back-end).

Comment: Did you see my answer? I tested it and it works.

Comment: I have been busy. I would test it out either tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with [rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and the [title module](http://www.drupal.org/project/title):

```
{ "rules_title_taxonomy_token" : {
    "LABEL" : "title taxonomy token",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : {
      "node_insert--package" : { "bundle" : "package" },
      "node_update--package" : { "bundle" : "package" }
    },
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "node:title-field" ],
          "value" : [ "node:field-my-taxonomy-field:0:name" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Be sure to change "package" to the name of your content type and be sure to use the proper field name for your taxonomy instead of field-my-taxonomy-field.

**As far as I know, the above only works with the [Title module](http://www.drupal.org/project/title) and the [Title Field UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/title_field_ui).**

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge.... but what should I do with that code ? Its that Rules that needs to be import into the Rules module ?

Comment: Yes install the rules module, set permissions, and use the rules import feature.

Comment: Sound great. I would try it out. Last question before I try it out....  I would need to enable title and disable with the title module. Right ?

Comment: Yes you enable the title module first, and then there's a checkbox or something that says replace your title with a field.

Comment: @Webripds, I try it out and did not work. I have update my question so you have an understanding that error that I'm seeing it.

Comment: However, I using your code I was able to replicated the same functionality by using the Rules UI. Thank you so much.